# mainMenu level window not displayed when switching desktops

Tags: macos, swiftui

As soon as I go full screen or change desktops, the mainMenu level window is not displayed in this new location, you have to go back to the previous one to see it.

Here is my code for this window:

```swift
Toolbar()
    .background(WindowStyle())
    .onAppear {
        let _ = NSApplication.shared.windows.map { 
            $0.tabbingMode = .disallowed 
        }
    }
```

```swift
struct WindowStyle: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let window = view.window {
                window.titleVisibility = .hidden
                window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
                window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
                window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
                window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
                window.level = .mainMenu
                window.collectionBehavior = [.fullScreenPrimary]
                window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            }
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
```

The goal is for it to be displayed permanently regardless of the desktop or screen situation. Do you have any idea?